# 2s compliment general form

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, bit-manipulation

Suppose I have a system that has integers that work in mod `n`.  So with my integers adding one to `n-1` is actually equal to zero.

Suppose further that you define the twos compliment of a number to be the number when added to itself is equal to zero. That is:

```
x + C(x) = 0   (here C(x) is the twos compliment of x)
```

What in general should I do to get the twos compliment of x?

**The real problem:**

If x is a number in binary I could just invert all of the the bits of x and then add one to that number.

This gets a little trickier if x is say a trinary number.  The problem with this is that it does not match up to an even number of bits, so you would be trying to flip 2/3 of a bit or something, which I don't have any clue what would mean physically.

So my question is this:  How can I take the two's compliment of a number of arbitrary base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you are working on base `s` for some integer `s > 0` and that you are trying to express quantities modulo `s^(n+1)` for some fixed integer `n > 0`. In other words using at most `n+1` places (or digits).

So, you represent integers in this system as sequences `[xn ... x0]` where every `xi` is a digit between `0` and `s-1`. For example, if `s=3` and `n=4`, the representation `[01201]` would correspond to the decimal number `0*3^4 + 1*3^3 + 2*3^2 + 0*3^1 + 1*3^0 = 27 + 18 + 1 = 46`.

Generally speaking the decimal value of the representation above would be:

```
x = xn*s^n + ... + x0*s^0
```

Now, your problem consists in finding the representation of `-x` modulo `s^(n+1)` (remember that we only can use `s+1` "digits".

Define, for every digit `xi` its *complement* to `s` as being

```
c(xi) = s - 1 - xi
```

Note that in the binary case, when `s=2`, the complemento to `2` conforms the same definition. Also notice that

```
xi + c(xi) = s - 1                                          eq(1)
```

Now let me use a simpler notation here and call `yi = c(xi)`. Then the sequence

```
y = [yn ... y0]
```

is what we could call *the complement to `s` of `x`*. It is also the representation of `-x - 1` modulo `s^(n+1)` and therefore to obtain `-x` you only have to add `1` to `y`. For example in the case `x=[01201]` we would have `y=[21021]` because the digits sum `3-1=2` at each position.

The reason is simple:

```
[yn ... y0] + [xn ... x0]
            = yn*s^n + ... + y0*s^0 + xn*s^n + ... + x0*s^n
            = (yn+xn)*s^n + ... + (y0+x0)*s^0
            = (s-1)*sˆn + ... + (s-1)*s^0              ; by eq(2)
            = s^(n+1) + ... + sˆ1 - (s^n + ... + s^0)
            = s^(n+1) - 1
            = -1  modulo s^(n+1)
```

So, things work similarly as how they work when `s=2` and, say, modulo `2^32` (32 bits). In this sense there is nothing special about the binary case.