# The logic behind 1's complement and 2's complement

Tags: logic, twos-complement, ones-complement

What is the logic behind obtaining the 1’s complement and 2’s complement by inverting the numbers and what is the mathematical reasoning behind this approches

Comment: There is a general explanation [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39681557/4081336)